# Weird, inconsistent behavior using Apache and multiple Django sites

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have two `mod_wsgi` django sites and four domain names. Two domains point to each site. When I visit my two sites using all four domains in chrome, they all work fine. But only most of the time. Sometimes, given a domain, the wrong site is suddenly displayed. Completely out of the blue.

This is becoming very confusing because the behavior is completely unpredictable. I follow some internal links on site A, and all of a sudden, a `404 error` from site B appears (naturally, the url couldn't be resolved in siteB's url's because it's a url from site A). I could refresh the page without changing the url and suddenly it would bring back site A. Or it would stay in the wrong site and `404` again, you just never know.

I've tried it on proxies (such as hidemyass.com) and the same unpredictable results happen.

The only predictability about it is that after `apachectl -k graceful`, there is no site switching for a while, but afterwards, it just happens every two pages. I assure you this was no bias.

Here's my httpd:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteA.tk
    ServerAlias siteA.tk
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteA/siteA/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /var/www/siteA/static/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteA.com
    ServerAlias siteA.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteA/siteA/wsgi.py

    Alias /static/ /var/www/siteA/static/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteB.tk
    ServerAlias siteB.tk

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteB/siteB/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteB.com
    ServerAlias siteB.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteB/siteB/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>


<Directory /var/www/siteA/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>



WSGIPythonPath /home/me/siteA:/home/me/siteB
```

Please help, I am so scared, it's like my computer's possessed by some Apache demon.

Comment: I think you need to use different path for each site in `WSGIScriptAlias`. Like `WSGIScriptAlias /siteAtk /home/me/siteA/siteA/wsgi.py` for www.siteA.tk

Comment: Still the same problem, and also can't run under root address with this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

This describes all the common reasons why you can get mixing of responses for sites when running Django under Apache/mod_wsgi.

In addition to that, you can also see issues if not careful where you have sites sharing a common parent domain. For this you may have to adjust cookie domains or names if each site was setup and is effectively sharing the same cookie.

Also be aware of sharing common backend services for all sites such as memcache as there can be contention as far as distinct sites use the same keys for data. For that setup things to use a distinct memcache key prefix to keep data separate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, combine identical sites like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteA.tk
    ServerAlias siteA.tk siteA.com www.siteA.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteA/siteA/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /var/www/siteA/static/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.siteB.tk
    ServerAlias siteB.tk siteB.com www.siteB.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/siteB/siteB/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, instead of using `WSGIPythonPath` in Apache configuration, add this line in the beginning of your `wsgi.py` file (this example is for siteA, change it properly for siteB):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/me/siteA')
```

Comment: Very good tips, thank you. However, it wouldn't have solved the problem I had, which I did find the solution to. I'm still waiting the 8 hours before being allowed to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Self realization.

The solution was to change the wsgi.py files generated by django. In fact it specifically says in the comments:

```
# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "siteA.settings"
```

I used the immediately simple option and replaced the given line below the comment with

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "yoursite.settings"
```

Restart apache

```
$ apachectl -k graceful
```

Problem solved.